# Как воспроизвести звук только один раз

Tags: javascript, php

Как при загрузке страницы проиграть звук только раз?
При перезагрузке(обновлении) или переходе со страницы на страницу не воспроизводить его повторно!

//Воспроизвести звук

```
$belfile = "../work/sound/bel.wav";

$audio = "<audio autoplay src='".$belfile."'></audio>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняйте некий идентификатор посетителя, например в сессии, и проверяйте его по условию. Как-то так:

```
session_start();

isset($_SESSION['audio']) ?: $_SESSION['audio'] = 0;

if (! $_SESSION['audio']) {
    $_SESSION['audio'] = 1;
    $belfile = "../work/sound/bel.wav";
    $audio = "<audio autoplay src='" . $belfile . "'></audio>";
}
```

Comment: За что минус-то? О.о Достойный ответ.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 вы у меня интересуетесь? Если да, то это не я минусовал ваш ответ. А если вы о минусе моего ответа - дак кто ж признается :)

Comment: я тому, кто поставил минус вашему ответу)

Comment: А возможно уничтожить сессию при закрытии браузера или сайта или через час работы на сайте, чтоб звук повторился? Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @Sergey да, обычно сессия "живёт" до закрытия браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы для этого использовал `JS` и `localStorage`.

Пример написан на `Jquery`

```
let isPlayAudio = 0; // создаём переменную для проверки

$(document).ready(function(){ // при прочтение страницы..
    let local = localStorage.getItem('myKey'); // проверяем есть ли наша проверка в хранилище
  if(local == 1) isPlayAudio = 1; // если у проверки из хранилища стоит "1", то звук не будет проигрываться, если нету ничего, то пропустит.
});

$(window).on('load', function(){ // Когда страница загружена..
    if(isPlayAudio != 1)    { // Проверяем можно ли запускать аудио
    let audio = new Audio(); // создаём объект аудио
    audio.src = 'https://sound-pack.net/download/Sound_16300.mp3'; // ссылка на звук
    audio.autoplay = true; // запускаем
    audio.volume = .3; // сделаем потише
    audio.remove(); // удаляем
    localStorage.setItem('playAudio', 1); // сохраняем значение для проверки
  }
});
```

Comment: Это не помогает, если обновлять страницу с помощью **ctr + f5**